# Can you represent an object that can have arbitrary fields in proto3?

Tags: protocol-buffers, proto

Consider the following json representation of an object

```
{
   "format":  "0.0.1",
   "has_impl": true,

   "mtv_1b": 1,
   "mtv_1c": "h",
   "ktc_12": true,
   "ktc_zz": true,
}
```

The first two `format` and `has_impl` fields are known. In addition, the object may have arbitrary number of `mtv_XX` and `ktc_XX` like fields.

Is such an object representable in proto3 and how would you go at it ?

The following could be an obvious starting point. Are there a combination of [oneOf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#oneof), [WellKnownTypes](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf) that could be used here ?

```
message MyObject {

   string format  = 0;
   bool has_impl = 1;


   // Is there anything that can go in here ? 
   ....

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not directly. The closest you can do would be to have a `Struct` (which is a `map<string, Value>`, where `Value` is a `oneof` over common types), using [struct.proto](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/struct.proto). Not quite the same, but allows the same ideas.

Comment: In the `Struct` approach I would be losing the ability to explicitly define the `format` and `has_impl` fields right ?

Comment: @HakanBaba you would lose the ability to define that *at the same level*; you could have a type that has `format`, `has_impl` *and* a `Struct`, though